# Displaying 'Working on it' for duplicate Item numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

| Item | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 7080 | On Hold |
| 7080 | Working on It |
| 7090 | On Hold |

When Item has same number i.e 7080 and has 'working on it' and 'hold' status, it should show 'Working on it' on both the status.

I wrote a solution, using a case expression, but did not work.

**Edit**: adaptation of @lemon's answer to my data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUBSTRING(item, 1, 4) Item,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(CASE 
                     WHEN [Eng Status] = 'Working on It' 
                         THEN 1 
                 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Item) = 1
            THEN 'Working on It'
            ELSE [Eng Status]
    END AS Status
FROM 
    tbl
```

Same result as previous, still not working.

| Item | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 7080 | On Hold |
| 7080 | Working on It |
| 7090 | On Hold |

**Edit:**

`select col1,col2 from tbl`

[image: Data]

This is the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea to use the same name for an expression as for the original column. You call your expression `item`, but it is actually just a substring of the original `item`. This confused you and you partitioned your `MAX OVER` by `item`. The DBMS doesn't yet see the alias you created and assumes the column. Here is the corrected query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUBSTRING(item, 1, 4) AS item,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(CASE 
                     WHEN [Eng Status] = 'Working on It' 
                         THEN 1 
                 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(item, 1, 4)) = 1
            THEN 'Working on It'
            ELSE [Eng Status]
    END AS Status
FROM 
    tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression to assign 'Working on It' to all those records that have at least one of that status "MAX(Status='Working') = 1" for each "*Item*".

```
SELECT Item,
       CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Status='Working on It' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Item)=1
            THEN 'Working on It'
            ELSE Status
       END AS Status
FROM tab
```

If you're using `SUBSTRING(item, 1, 4)` instead of `Item`, you also need `OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(item, 1, 4))`.

Comment: btw I'm using a view . I got this msg 'Update or insert of view or function 'cte' failed because it contains a derived or constant field'. @lemon

Comment: If you don't need any update, it's much simpler, and you just need what's contained inside cte. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Other items with just 'On hold' status is showing as null.

Comment: Don't leave comments, update your post with wide use cases and ping me here.

Comment: It can't help if I can't see why it doesn't work. Let me see it with data, and maybe there's some easy fix to it.

Comment: I have added the data

Comment: I guess the simple correction that this code needed, is the one reported by Thorsten on a brand separate answer. Your first selected field must be the same one in the `PARTITION BY`. If you use `SUBSTRING(item, 1, 4) AS Item`, you also need to use `SUBSTRING(item, 1, 4)` inside the `PARTITION BY`.